# Error while creating virtual machine X The requested size for resource Y is currently not available in location Z

Tags: azure, azure-devtest-labs

I've currently created Test Lab in Azure and when I try to create an `Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS` it keeps failing with the below error message.

> Error while creating virtual machine TestVMUbuntu The requested size
>   for resource
>   `/subscriptions/....../resourceGroups/blockchaineuropetest/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/TestVMUbuntu`
>   is currently not available in location 'northeurope' zones '' for
>   subscription 'xxxxxxx'. Please try
>   another size or deploy to a different location or zones. See
>   https://aka.ms/azureskunotavailable for details.

I connected with PowerShell remote and it's on the list of available regions.

```
PS C:\Users\joshua.duxbury> Get-AzureRmLocation | select DisplayName

DisplayName
-----------
East Asia
Southeast Asia
Central US
East US
East US 2
West US
North Central US
South Central US
North Europe
West Europe
Japan West
Japan East
Brazil South
Australia East
Australia Southeast
South India
Central India
West India
Canada Central
Canada East
UK South
UK West
West Central US
West US 2
Korea Central
Korea South
France Central
France South
```

I've tried a few different regions. Has anyone else encountered this issue and how can I resolve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The region I chose was available, the reason I was running into this problem was that I hosted the VM's on a `Visual Studio Professional` subscription and I was trying to host a VM with premium disks.

I followed the below steps.

1. Make sure the region is available (which it was available)
2. Select HDD instead of SSD.
3. Look down the list of available none premium VM's (green instead of blue)

Comment: Just to add:  Even if you follow these steps, `Spot Instance` is still not available for `Visual Studio Professional` subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

You will receive this error if you are using a Visual Studio subscription, and you are trying to create a Spot Instance.  This also applies to some other types of 'free' subscriptions - the list of offer codes which support Spot Instances is short, and can be found at the link below (the offer code for your subscription can be found on the main 'Overview' page of your subscription in the Azure Portal - most 'typical' subscriptions will be Pay-as-you-Go or EA).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/spot-vms#limitations

Answer (score 0):

What size did you try to create?

Below series are not available in the North Europe region:

Fv2-series,

G-series,

M-series,

GS-series,

NCv2-series,

NCv3-series,

ND-Series,

L-Series.

You can find products available by region [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/).